# No folders android and ios

Tags: android, react-native, create-react-native-app

Why after `create-react-native-app` I don't have a folder android and ios?
Now I can't open this by `react-native run-android` and can't put for example android permissions.
What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are **two ways** to create React native project.

1. `create-react-native-app AwesomeProject` => This used expo to create app and when you use this command to create app you will not find `android` and `ios` folder you cant add platform specific libraries.
2. `react-native-init` => this app is not created using expo you can find android and ios folder and can do native coding or use platform specific libraries as well as permission you mention.

In your case want to add permissions:

If you wish to do native coding (android and ios) or want to install Platform specific libraries i.e. `npm link` you need to run `npm run eject` command

(**Note**: Once you run `eject` command you can't run your app using expo. So before doing this go through docs)

Comment: if i run eject, how to back again for using expo ?

Comment: no no there is no way to undo this that why I put Note in bold

Answer (score 0):

you should `run react-native init projectName`.pay attention you should run cmd as `run as administrator`

Comment: but now i can't run my app n in expo

Answer (score 0):

Naviagte to project path and execute the following command to get android and ios folder

```
1. > npm i    //To get all dependencies loaded
2. > react-native upgrade //To get android and ios folder
3. > react-native link  //To link the dependencies to ios and android
4. > react-native run-android or react-native run-ios
```

Comment: do you  know why i need to do it manually ? i dont see this in officla doc

Comment: Kindly see this link https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading